# Laptop is not working with the wireless home network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I got an old laptop that I have upgraded to Windows 7 Home Premium (Was Win Vista originally when bought). Any Way, my sister took it for a while as her machine was having issues, when she return it. The machine is connected to the wireless home network (it had taken the IP of the home network) but no connectivity !!!. I tried everything I know in order to fix the issue but not use, here what I did.

1 - tried the local utility of windows to fix the issue but it reported that it cant find the gateway (failed).
2 - ipconfig /release and /renew to renew the IP (failed).
3 - removing the driver and reinstalling it again, note that I got the driver throw windows update, I deleted it in the machine and redownloaded again (failed).
4 - I thought to could be related to a virus, I did a full virus scan and it was not infected (failed).

My last option now is to format that machine and redo everything again, only after this I can say that the adapter hardware is having a issue.

Kindly advice me before doing the last option.

thanks,

Comment: please post results of `ipconfig /all`

Comment: Can you ping out to your gateway? can you ping out to your primary DNS? can you ping google? can you ping google's IP? What, if anything, changes when the laptop is plugged in? Have you tried a secondary wi-fi adapter? Do other device work on the wireless network? Can the laptop connect to any other wireless networks?